# Combine NSManagedObject classes

Tags: swift, swift4

I have multiple `NSManagedObject` classes that I am extending with a temp variable, returning its instance from another context. The method below works fine, but it's kind of tedious with a lot of classes.

I tried to extend `NSManagedObject`, but I wasn't able to return the specific class type since NSManagedObject is non-generic.

Is it possible to combine all of these into one extension variable, yet still retain the ability to return the class type as it currently does?

```
extension Account {
    var temp: Account {
        return core.temporaryContext.object(with: self.objectID) as! Account
    }
}


extension Transaction {
    var temp: Transaction {
        return core.temporaryContext.object(with: self.objectID) as! Transaction
    }
}


extension Category {
    var temp: Category {
        return core.temporaryContext.object(with: self.objectID) as! Category
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put the functionality into a protocol and its possible since we talk about a computed property instead of a stored one(which cannot be added by protocol).

You write the empty protocol and the extension you want the protocol to implement first and then you add what the extension requires to the protocol definition.

```
public protocol FetchRequestProtocol: class {
    var objectID: NSManagedObjectID { get }
}

protocol TemporaryProtocol: FetchRequestProtocol {
    var core: Core { get }
}
extension TemporaryProtocol {
    var temp: Self {
        return core.temporaryContext.object(with: self.objectID) as! Self
    }
}

extension Account: TemporaryProtocol {}
extension Transaction: TemporaryProtocol {}
extension Category: TemporaryProtocol {}
```